# Bash script processing snmp text to only print desired ID

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting

I am trying to create a bash script handling snmp responses the same way whether or not the OID is installed on the client.

Clients can get the following responses:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.47.1.1.1.1.13.1062 STRING: "GLC-SX-MMD          "

iso.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.13.1062 STRING: "GLC-SX-MMD          "
```

I want to get the last part, 1062, which is the id number. What these responses share is 47.1.1.1.1.13.(id number).

How can I process the text to print id number only regardless of how the client reponse looks in the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can remove everything except a number following digits and dots:

```
sed -e 's/.*[0-9.]*\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

Explanation:

```
.*         anything
[0-9.]*    digits and dots in any order
\.         dot
\(         start a matching group
  [0-9]*   digits
\)         end the matching group
.*         anything
```

All the matching string is replaced with the matching group, i.e. the last number after digits and dots.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Would you mind breaking down how this works?

Comment: @Sebbeleu: Check the update.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you can be sure of is that you want a string of digits that comes after `47.1.1.1.1.13.`, you could use one of:

```
grep -Po '47\.1\.1\.1\.1\.13.\K\d+'
sed -n 's/.*47\.1\.1\.1\.1\.13\.\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
perl -lne '/47\.1\.1\.1\.1\.13\.(\d+)/ && print $1'
```

If, as in your example, the target string is always before `STRING`, you could use:

```
grep -Po '\d+(?= STRING)' 
sed -n 's/.*\.\([0-9]\+\) STRING.*/\1/p' 
perl -lne '/(\d+)(?= STRING)/ && print $1'
```

Alternatively, if the target string is always the first occurrence of a dot, a string of numbers and a space, which is what you show in your question, you can do:

```
grep -Po '^\S+\.\K\d+' 
sed -n 's/^[^ \t]*\.\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
perl -lne '/^\S+\.(\d+)/ && print $1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Remove two substrings from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056320/remove-two-substrings-from-a-string):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ resp1='SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.47.1.1.1.1.13.1062 STRING: "GLC-SX-MMD          "'
$ resp2='iso.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.13.1062 STRING: "GLC-SX-MMD          "'
$ echo ${resp1//@(*47.1.1.1.1.13.| STRING*)}
1062
$ echo ${resp2//@(*47.1.1.1.1.13.| STRING*)}
1062
```